# Dalvik-Cache / Android

Tags: android, dalvik

What is in /data/dalvik-cache ?

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and its using 127Mb of the entire ROM space, making the phone always display a "full space" message and making me unable to download any apps.

Can it be cleared ? How ?

Thanks.

Comment: it's where apps are uncompressed. that's necessary to run an app. uninstall apps to make room

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541281/what-is-dalvik-and-dalvik-cache/7541404#7541404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dalvik cache is an essential part of your Android. You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29

Clearing the cache would cause your phone to run slowly as the cache is recreated, and then you'd be right back where you are now.

To solve your actual problem, you could try using an app like App2SD to free up some space.