# Android Run Time(ART) working? What is happening to .dex files?

Tags: android, android-studio

What is happenig to .dex files while running an application ?
for testing this i deleted an .dex file [whatsapp] from "data/dalvic-cache" and then i run that application.  it works perfectly.
to my knowledge .dex files are created when the installation time of an application.
**My question is why we need a .dex file and how the ART is using it?**

Comment: just a guess, you removed a file from _cache_ so it got recreated...?

Comment: If you know java very well then you have idea for JVM, same like that Android has DVM dalvik virtual machine which convert the code in special bytecode which is stored in this .dex file means dalvik executablew file, so whenever you run the application first same like java app, app will compile and generate executable file and then it will run.

Comment: @lelloman no. that's the problem.. it do not re-created. still the app is working. but i think its little slow now. i am on cyanogen mode. lolipop 5.1

Comment: ok I think [this is your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7541404/1527232)

Answer (score 0):

yes. . my conclusion is .dex files are not created when we launch the app. and by my experiment i think without .dex files in dalvic-cache application will work(but slow), and when we restarts the system android optimizes the app and Re-Creates the .dex file. and one other thing is now there is no Dalvic Virtual Machine, in android vr. 5.0 or above have only ART.(which replaces the Dalvic Virtual Machine).