# App crashes on launch if installed to system partition

Tags: android, permissions, crash, android-install-apk

I am trying to install an APK as a system app in `/system/app`

when I install it as a nurmal user app to `data/app`, everything works fine.
when I try to install different app as a system app, it works fine

but for this app, is crashes with the error
`E/dalvikvm( 1533): Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache`.
every other app works fine and there is plenty of space on `/data` partition.

`/data/dalvik-cache` has `drwxrwx--x` permission.
after running `chmod 777 /data/dalvik-cache` the app was open correctly!

The question is: why does android have a write problem to `/data/dalvik-cache`, only when the app is install as system app, and only for this app.
I also notice that the icon size is smaller when installed as system app. is there a different parsing method for system app's then user app's?

android version: 4.4

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Pasted:**
*The Dalvik cache is the set of saved. dex files. A . dex file is basically a compiled bytecode version of an app that has been built for the Dalvik Virtual Machine on which Android's apps run*

If you study the file system in general all the partitions which are intended to be used only by the system, are to have limited or no permissions for users because there is a potential risk of damaging the file system,

If particular if you need to see why the Dalvik folder do please have a look at
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541281/what-is-dalvik-and-dalvik-cache)

Comment: thank you for the respond. its not answering way the process that generate the byte code cache does not have writing permission to ```/data/dalvik-cache``` only for one app and only if install as system app